# PHP error logging with AWS and EC2

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, logging

I'm setting up my site to run on AWS EC2. In some presentation for AWS services I saw that there are ways to store your PHP error logs in AWS S3 and analyze it with specific tools. Can't find this presentation and can't find it by googling. Anyone?

Answer (score 1):

You're in luck, AWS just announced the ability to ship and analyze logs through CloudWatch.

http://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/cloudwatch-log-service/